# What is the namespace keyword

Tags: php, namespaces, expression

I'm reading the PHP reference manual and I'm faced with the following code snippet:

```
<?php
namespace foo;
use My\Full\Classname as Another;
use My\Full\NSname;
use ArrayObject;

$obj = new namespace\Another; //I don't understand this line
$obj = new Another; 
NSname\subns\func();
$a = new ArrayObject(array(1)); 
?>
```

Can you explain how does `namespace` statement resolving? I'm looking for this in the [php expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) but I can't.

Comment: What exactly are you wondering about? PHP as extensive documentation about namespaces: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php The line you marked means that a new instance of class `Another` from the current namespace is created. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php.

Comment: @FelixKling Here is the quote from php reference: `If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created. If the class is in a namespace, its fully qualified name must be used when doing this.`. In my case the string is `namespace\Another`. But namespace statement must be evaluated before the constructor is invoked. In the `namespace foo;` it's just defined `foo` namespace, but in string which I marked it is resolved as `foo`. Why? Where is it specified in the reference?

Comment: As I said and as you can read on the page I linked to, `namespace` is a special keyword that refers to the current namespace. The section you quoted does not apply in your situation because you are not working with a string here. `namespace\Another` is not a string. Have a look again at the example that belongs to the part you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the following classes

a - namespace foo
b - namespace bar
c - no namespace

then if you include these files and call them

a would be new foo\a
b would be new bar\b
c would be new c

I use namespaces to make easy autoloading so you can use the namespace to be the directory for example new mynamespace\database\connector would mean the class exists in database directory and the file is called connector.php so you dont have to have a section including all the class files